# Flux backpressure not applied

Tags: java, stream, project-reactor

I have an endless stream of events, which I want to:

1. take into microbatches, 100ms each, or 10000 elements
2. group them based on a grouping function
3. process each list of grouped items in parallel

my code looks like following:

```
Flux<SuchEvent> suchFlux = Flux.fromStream(events);
Scheduler parallel = Schedulers.newParallel("asd", 64);
suchFlux
            .bufferTimeout(10000, Duration.ofMillis(100))
            .map(rawEvents -> {
                Map<UUID, List<SuchEvent>> groupedEvents = new HashMap<>();
                for (SuchEvent stuff : rawEvents) {
                    if (!groupedEvents.containsKey(stuff.getProfileId())) {
                        groupedEvents.put(stuff.getProfileId(), new ArrayList<>());
                    }
                    groupedEvents.get(stuff.getProfileId()).add(stuff);
                }
                return groupedEvents.values();
            })
            .subscribe(groupedEvents -> {
                for (List<SuchEvent> suchEvents : groupedEvents) {
                    Flux.fromIterable(suchEvents)
                        .subscribeOn(parallel)
                        .subscribe(suchEvent -> {
                            //do stuff (this is fairly slow, each call takes 50ms)
                        });
                }
            });
```

I'd expect the internal subscribe(suchEvent) to cause some backpressure to the producing, however, after running for a while everything seems to grind down to a halt. Where is the fallacy in my logic?

Comment: Is your events an infinite stream ?

Comment: yes, it is more or less, an infinite stream.

Answer (score 3):

When you subscribe with a lambda it it will trigger an unbounded request. To fine tune back-pressure you need to implements your own [Subscriber](http://www.reactive-streams.org/reactive-streams-1.0.1-javadoc/org/reactivestreams/Subscriber.html?is-external=true).

The recommended solution for this is to extends from [BaseSubscriber](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/BaseSubscriber.html).

In the reactor documentation they provide useful informations about it:

> The bare minimum implementation is to implement both hookOnSubscribe(Subscription subscription) and hookOnNext(T value).

So you could do something like:

```
public static class SubscriberWithBackPressure<T> extends BaseSubscriber<T> {
    private final int maxRequest;
    private final Consumer<T> consumer;

    public SubscriberWithBackPressure(int maxRequest, Consumer<T> consumer) {
        this.maxRequest = maxRequest;
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void hookOnSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
        subscription.request(maxRequest);
    }

    @Override
    protected void hookOnNext(T value) {
        if (consumer != null) {
            this.consumer.accept(value);
        }
        request(maxRequest);
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
suchFlux
        .bufferTimeout(10000, Duration.ofMillis(100))
        .map(rawEvents -> {
            Map<UUID, List<SuchEvent>> groupedEvents = new HashMap<>();
            for (SuchEvent stuff : rawEvents) {
                if (!groupedEvents.containsKey(stuff.getProfileId())) {
                    groupedEvents.put(stuff.getProfileId(), new ArrayList<>());
                }
                groupedEvents.get(stuff.getProfileId()).add(stuff);
            }
            return groupedEvents.values();
        })
        .subscribe(groupedEvents -> {
            for (List<SuchEvent> suchEvents : groupedEvents) {
                Flux.fromIterable(suchEvents)
                    .subscribeOn(parallel)
                    .subscribe(new SubscriberWithBackPressure<>(100, suchEvent -> /*do stuff*/));
            }
        });
```

An updated version (not sure that backpressure is handled on each transformation level):

```
suchFlux.bufferTimeout(10000, Duration.ofMillis(100))
    .map(events -> events.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SuchEvent::getProfileId)))
    .flatMap(group -> Flux.fromStream(group.values().stream()))
    .flatMap(suchEvents -> Flux.fromIterable(suchEvents))
    .subscribeOn(parallel)
    .subscribe(new SubscriberWithBackPressure<>(100, suchEvent -> System.out.println(suchEvent)));
```

Comment: second solution is more idiomatic and should handle backpressure, although note that flatMap rewrites the backpressure by prefetching 256 elements by default, so if you don't want that you might need to tune each flatmap with an additional `prefetch` parameter.